# Consistent pseudo-random numbers across platforms

Tags: c++, c, random

I am looking for a way to generate pseudo random number sequences that will yield identical sequence results for a given seed across any platform. I am assuming that `rand()` / `srand()` is not going to be consistent (I could easily be wrong about this assumption).

Comment: see my question and answer for C++11 random generators. The C++11 mt19937 delivers consistent results across all platforms, but the standard distributions do not, so I created my own distributions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903356/c11-random-number-distributions-are-not-consistent-across-platforms-what-al

Comment: If you choose to use linear congruential generators, [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) is useful. In particular you could use the C implementation of `rand` suggested in the ISO/IEC 9899. In my tests it gave identical results when `unsigned long` is using 32 (the minimum) or 64 bits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like a [Mersenne Twister (from Boost.Random)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/random/random-generators.html#mt19937) is deterministic.

Comment: If you'd rather avoid Boost, you can use the original implementation of the [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html), which was written in straight C.  In recent years, the MT group has added some additional ports that can make use of SIMD, OpenCL, and CUDA.

Comment: see my question and answer for C++11 random generators. The C++11 mt19937 delivers consistent results across all platforms, but the standard distributions do not, so I created my own distributions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903356/c11-random-number-distributions-are-not-consistent-across-platforms-what-al

Answer (score 8):

Knuth has [released into the public domain C (and FORTRAN) source code](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/news02.html#rng) for the pseudo-random number generator described in section 3.6 of *The Art of Computer Programming*.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old thread but now with C++11 there are a whole bunch of [new options available](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Here is a distilled example from the page which defaults to using the `Mersenne Twister` engine and `Normal` distribution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    //
    // Engines 
    //
    std::mt19937 e2(rd());
    //std::knuth_b e2(rd());
    //std::default_random_engine e2(rd()) ;

    //
    // Distribtuions
    //
    std::normal_distribution<> dist(2, 2);
    //std::student_t_distribution<> dist(5);
    //std::poisson_distribution<> dist(2);
    //std::extreme_value_distribution<> dist(0,2);

    std::map<int, int> hist;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
        ++hist[std::round(dist(e2))];
    }

    for (auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::setw(2)
                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*') << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: The distributions specified by the C++11 standard are **not** required to yield reproducible results given the same seed, even when using the same code.  Let alone using different libraries, like libc++ vs libstdc++.

Comment: see my question and answer for C++11 random generators. The C++11 mt19937 delivers consistent results across all platforms, but the standard distributions do not, so I created my own distributions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903356/c11-random-number-distributions-are-not-consistent-across-platforms-what-al

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a [`simplerandom`](https://github.com/cmcqueen/simplerandom) library for this. It is supposed to be cross-platform, and I also aim to target multiple languages. Currently it supports C and [Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplerandom) (same numbers generated in both languages). I plan to implement the same generators in C++ soon, following the Boost and C++11 random API.

Answer (score 0):

A quickly googled [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) says:

> Two different initializations with the same seed, instructs the pseudo-random generator to generate the same succession of results for the subsequent calls to rand in both cases.

But the question remains. I assume the above spec only applies to RNGs within the same process. It most likely doesn't specify anything about cross-platform or cross-compiler things. Your best bet is probably to find a library that is available for all desired platforms. Then you should be reasonably safe that if seeded with the same value they return the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: I believe this refers to he behavior of any particular implementation of `rand()`, and does not provide any cross-compiler or cross-platform assurance. Moreover, with built-in PRNGs you risk all kinds of unwanted properties. Use a library with a PRNG known to be appropriate for your needs.