# Does stdlib's rand() always give the same sequence?

Tags: c, random, c-standard-library

I quite like being able to generate the same set of pseudo-random data repeatedly, especially with tweaking experimental code. Through observation I would say that `rand()` seems to give the same sequence of numbers each time*.

Is it guaranteed to do this for repeated executions on the same machine / for different machines / for different architectures?

*For the same seed obviously.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, given the same environment for the program. From the C standard §7.20.2.2/2,

> The `srand` function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to `rand`. **If `srand` is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated.** If `rand` is called before any calls to `srand` have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when `srand` is first called with a seed value of 1.

Of course, this assumes it is using the same implementation detail (i.e. same machine, same library at the same execution period). The C standard does not mandate a standard random number generating algorithm, thus, if you run the program with a different C standard library, one may get a different random number sequence.

See the question [*Consistent pseudo-random numbers across platforms*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922358/consistent-pseudo-random-numbers-across-platforms) if you need a portable and guaranteed random number sequence with a given seed.

Comment: OK. I agree that for a particular runtime lib the sequence will be the same. So once an application is built (against a specific runtime version) it will always generate the same sequence. But does this extent to different version of the runtime (ie across OS/architecture/runtime versions) etc. If it does that would imply that the standard defines an exact implementation for the rand() algorithm (otherwise how would two independent OS make sure they conform).

Comment: It doesn't extend across different versions of the runtimes - and if you dynamically link to the implementation of `rand()` it could potentially act differently without rebuilding anything.

Comment: @Martin: *But does this extent to different version of the runtime* — no. Actually, it depends on the runtime whether an update will change the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The tweaking stage only happens on one machine (I added the extended questions for completeness).

Comment: The language in the Standard only guarantees that you'll get the same sequence every time you call `srand()` with the same value *during one execution of the program* (the *"If `srand` is then called..."* implies that it happens within the same program).  It would be conforming for an implementation to pick a "master seed" at program startup, which perturbs the algorithm different each time the program is run.

Answer (score 2):

It is guaranteed to give the same sequence for the same seed passed to `srand()` - but *only for the duration of a single execution of the program*.  In general, if an implementation has a choice in behaviour, there is no specific requirement for that choice to remain the same across subsequent executions.

It would be conforming for an implementation to pick a "master seed" at each program startup, and use that to perturb the pseudo-random number generator in a way that is different each time the program starts.

If you wish for more determinism, you should implement a PRNG with specific parameters in your program.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The C standard says:

> If srand is then called with the same
>   seed value, the sequence of
>   pseudo-random numbers shall be
>   repeated.

But nowhere does it say what the sequence of pseudo-random numbers actually is - so it differs across implementations.

The only guarantee made is that `rand()` will give the same sequence of numbers for a given seed *for a given implementation*. There's no guarantee that the sequence will be the same across different machines or different architectures - and it almost certainly won't be.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the exact same set of pseudo-random numbers for experimental purposes, one thing you could do is to use `srand` to generate a long sequence of random numbers and write them to a file/database.  Then, write a portable "random number generator" function that returns values sequentially from that file.  That way, you can be assured that you are using the same input data regardless of the platform, `srand` implementation, or seed value.

Comment: Nice idea. If I had a requirement to do that, I would certainly take that approach. My question was borne more out of curiosity than the need for a known sequence.

Comment: Or you could just write a random function of your own?

Answer (score 0):

When switching to a different machine/runtime/whatever you might be out of luck. There is another possible choice the `drand48` family of functions. These are normalized to use the same algorithm on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a UNIX/Linux enviroment you can see the **drand48()** and **srand48(**) at your man pages if you are not you can see [online manuals](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/3/drand48/) for the C Language.
The prototypes can be found at **/usr/include/stdlib.h** .
The first one use the Linear Congruential Method that is frequently used in Simulations.

If you provide the same seed to srand48() i.e. srand48(2) and then put the dran48() in a for loop then the sequence will be the same every time.
i.e.

```
include stdio.h
include stdlib.h
double drand48();
int main(void){
    int i;
    double rn;
    srand48(2);
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        randNum = drand48();
        printf("%.6l\n", randNum);
        return 0;
}
```