# srand() is outputting the wrong values

Tags: c++

So I'm making a selection sort program where I have to input two values: one for the numbers to use in the array, and the seed to use for the random number generator. I'm just a little confused on how to adjust the number used, since the maximum number of elements we can put in is 15. The array currently has 8. Each element should be a number between 20 and 40.

```css
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int selectionSort(int[], int);

int selectionSort(int numbers[], int numbersSize) {
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int indexSmallest = 0;
int temp = 0;  // Temporary variable for swap

for (i = 0; i < numbersSize - 1; ++i) {

// Find index of smallest remaining element
indexSmallest = i;
for (j = i + 1; j < numbersSize; ++j) {

if (numbers[j] < numbers[indexSmallest]) {
indexSmallest = j;
}
}

// Swap numbers[i] and numbers[indexSmallest]
temp = numbers[i];
numbers[i] = numbers[indexSmallest];
numbers[indexSmallest] = temp;
}
return indexSmallest;
}

int main() {
int numbers[] = {10, 2, 78, 4, 45, 32, 7, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
const int NUMBERS_SIZE = 15;
int i = 0;
int nums = 0;
int seed = 0;

cin >> nums;
cin >> seed;

srand(seed);

for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
numbers[i] = (rand() % 20) + 20;
}

cout << "UNSORTED: ";
for (i = 0; i < nums; ++i) {
cout << numbers[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;

selectionSort(numbers, nums);

cout << "SORTED: ";
for (i = 0; i < nums; ++i) {
cout << numbers[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

The only problem is that the random numbers being generated are the wrong numbers. For example, when I input "10 100" (10 for the numbers being used in the array and 100 for the seed), it outputs

> UNSORTED: 25 36 35 24 24 34 38 22 29 29
>
> SORTED: 22 24 24 25 29 29 34 35 36 38

when it should be outputting

> UNSORTED: 28 28 34 37 36 27 33 36 36 39
>
> SORTED: 27 28 28 33 34 36 36 36 37 39

I'm not really sure how to fix this.

Comment: Why do you think srand(100) should produce 28 as the first number?  I think it depends on the compiler.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503825/does-stdlibs-rand-always-give-the-same-sequence

Comment: How can random values be right or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot to say about this code:

- The initial values put into the array `numbers[]` will of course be overwritten.
- `NUMBERS_SIZE` is not used.
- If you want to be able to specify the array length as input parameter, you should use a `std::vector<>`, or create the array dynamically, or at least check that the given number of values doesn't exceed the array size.
- `rand()` is a random number generator, `srand()` sets some kind of seed for these random numbers. It is guaranteed that with the same seed you will always get the same sequence of random numbers.
  But, why/how do you expect to know the numbers that will be generated?
- Indention.
- Don't do `using namespace std;`

The answer to your question would be: Don't use random numbers.

Comment: I kind of have to though. My instructions say "The second input should be the seed for the random number generator."

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374800/c-srand-does-not-give-same-sequences-of-random-numbers and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503825/does-stdlibs-rand-always-give-the-same-sequence In short: if you use the same seed in the **same environment** (i.e. same machine, same library at the same execution period), you will have the same sequence. So it is expected that you have diffent sequences in different environments.

Comment: @JohnSmith There is nothing wrong with that, but then you cannot expect to get specific values!

Comment: @Ilya Thank you for the clarification. I silently assumed that the OP is running the program always in the same environment.

Answer (score -1):

You may try rand function

`/* initialize random seed: */
srand (time(NULL));
 /* generate random number betwee 1 and 10: */
 iSecret = rand() % 10 + 1;`

you need also to include 3 libraries

`#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */`

`#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */`

`#include <time.h>       /* time */`

Comment: And how does copying documentation answer the question?