# C/C++ algorithm to produce same pseudo-random number sequences from same seed on different platforms?

Tags: c++, c, random, portability, consistency

The title says it all, I am looking for something preferably stand-alone because I don't want to add more libraries.

Performance should be good since I need it in a tight high-performance loop. I guess that will come at a cost of the degree of randomness.

Comment: Have a look at C++11 [random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library.

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922358/consistent-pseudo-random-numbers-across-platforms

Comment: @Antoine - will it produce the same sequences across different implementations?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour - not really, I have more specific requirements.

Comment: @ddriver: default initialization values may be different but if you specify your own settings instead of the default one, yes (because algorithms are well specified). For instance `std::linear_congruential_engine<int, 16807, 0, (1u << 31) - 1>

Comment: @ddriver: values from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any particular pseudo-random number generation algorithm will behave like this. The problem with `rand` is that it's not specified how it is implemented. Different implementations will behave in different ways and even have varying qualities.

However, C++11 provides the new [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) standard library header that contains lots of great random number generation facilities. The random number engines defined within are well-defined and, given the same seed, will always produce the same set of numbers.

For example, a popular high quality random number engine is `std::mt19937`, which is the Mersenne twister algorithm configured in a specific way. No matter which machine, you're on, the following will always produce the same set of real numbers between 0 and 1:

```
std::mt19937 engine(0); // Fixed seed of 0
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  std::cout << dist(engine) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna test this right away.

Comment: fix in your code  std::mt19337 to std::mt19937.

Comment: Is this true? Is something like mt19937 guaranteed to produce the same results across all platforms?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Pseudocode)

Here [is another another PRNG implementation in C](http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/prng.c).

You may find a [collection of PRNG here](http://random.mat.sbg.ac.at/results/karl/server/).

Here's the simple classic PRNG:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned int PRNG()
{
    // our initial starting seed is 5323
    static unsigned int nSeed = 5323;

    // Take the current seed and generate a new value from it
    // Due to our use of large constants and overflow, it would be
    // very hard for someone to predict what the next number is
    // going to be from the previous one.
    nSeed = (8253729 * nSeed + 2396403); 

    // Take the seed and return a value between 0 and 32767
    return nSeed  % 32767;
}

int main()
{
  // Print 100 random numbers
    for (int nCount=0; nCount < 100; ++nCount)
    {
        cout << PRNG() << "\t";

        // If we've printed 5 numbers, start a new column
        if ((nCount+1) % 5 == 0)
            cout << endl;
    }
}
```