# Is the sequence of random numbers generated by rand, in C, guaranteed to always be the same, for the same seed?

Tags: c, random

I was just wondering if the `rand` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) function will generate the same sequence of random numbers, while using the **same seed**, when run on **different** `libc` implementations, and even different compilers and operating systems (win, linux).

I did some tests using various compilers( g++4.8, g++5.1 and clang) and it *seems* that the answer is yes, however I did not find any "official" mention of the PRNG algorithm used in the C's random number generation (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/rand.html), or whether these should be mentioned in the standards ...

Comment: From the link you posted (posix): `If srand() is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated.`. C11, §7.22.2.2 has the same wording.

Comment: @P.P. yes, It's just not clear for me whether the sequence will be the same on a different computer too, using a different compiler.

Comment: I suspect that you have compared three implementations of the same generator, two of which (the g++ ones) are identical.

Comment: @Lundin Those two discuss how to get consistent results across platforms, but they don't directly discuss whether `rand` has a standard implementation.

Comment: @pjs How is that not the same thing? The latter leads to the former.

Comment: @Lundin There's a difference between an implicit answer and an explicit one.  It's easier for people to miss or overlook the former than the latter.

Comment: @pjs I haven't cast any close votes, because I don't know enough about random number generators. However, the sheer amount of duplicates does indicate that this has been asked many times before.

Comment: @Lundin It's a judgement call.  I thought about casting a close vote, but decided having an explicit answer was worth something, in part because of the very first comment indicated how the standard could be misinterpreted.

Comment: @P.P. That only says that a single libc implementation must be consistent between calls to `seed`, not that different implementation must all produce the same sequence. Moreover if that was the meaning then the standard would have to also provide the exact algorithm to produce the "standard sequence" so that people can write conforming implementations, otherwise the request is unreasonable.

Comment: Note that at least on OpenBSD, they've made it so rand() returns actual random byes, (so different on each run of the program). I think this violates some standards. https://lwn.net/Articles/625506/

Comment: @Buge: yeah, but the question is about what happens "in C", and since that implementation doesn't conform to the standard it's not C ;-p In practice, almost everyone who needs repeatable random numbers, for modelling or whatever, won't be using `rand()` anyway because there's no guarantee of quality even good enough for a game of Snakes and Ladders.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no guarantee in the standard about what will be generated:

From the standard:

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence
>   produced and some implementations are known to produce sequences with
>   distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with particular
>   requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufficient for
>   their needs.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Answer (score 22):

Not even `RAND_MAX` is specified to have a given value across C implementations other than it must be >= 32767.  So `rand()` on one implementation can return a different range of values than on another and thus a different sequence.

> The `rand` function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the 
>   range 0 to `RAND_MAX`.  C11dr §7.22.2.1 2
>
> The value of the `RAND_MAX` macro shall be at least 32767. C11dr §7.22.2.1 5
>
> `RAND_MAX` which expands to an integer constant expression that is the maximum value returned by the rand function §7.22 3

Even with the the same `RAND_MAX`, note [@Servé Laurijssen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37390155/2410359) answer: the sequence of values from `rand()` may differ.

---

Note: by implication, `RAND_MAX <= INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15500754/1994390 the answer is no. There's no guarantee across different implementations.