# METIS: different results on different OS

Tags: c, metis

This [C program](https://github.com/dfroger/quickstart/blob/a7a8f897de15e0081ddf3c54576ba66677d72ed2/metis/main.c) calls [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/views/metis) to partition a mesh.

**Edit:** [New version](https://github.com/dfroger/quickstart/blob/a05c861119970fe72e02605652a5a92034dee5df/metis/main.c) of the C program taking into account comments of WeatherVane and PaulOgilvie.

On my `GNU/Linux` I get the results:

```
objval: 14
epart: 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 
npart: 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 
8
```

while on my `OSX` I get:

```
objval: 17
epart: 0 1 1 0 1 0 2 2 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 0 
npart: 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 2 2 2 0 2 2 0 0 
8
```

What causes the results to be different?

How to fix it, I mean, always get the same results whatever the OS/architecture/compiler is?

Note: `idx_t` is `int64_t`, which is `long` on my `GNU/Linux`, but `long long` on my `OSX`.

## My GNU/Linux

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS \n \l

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ uname -s -r -v -p -i -o
Linux 3.5.0-45-generic #68~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 16:18:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## My OSX

```
$ sw_vers 

ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F34

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

$ uname -m -p -r -s -v
Darwin 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386
```

## METIS installation

`METIS` version is 5.1.0

I have installed `METIS` with [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).

The packages are [here](https://binstar.org/freshkiss3d/metis/files)
(files `linux-64/metis-5.1.0-0.tar.bz2` and `osx-64/metis-5.1.0-2.tar.bz2`).

These packages have been built with this [recipe](https://github.com/dfroger/df-conda-recipe/tree/16cd577915d245d087550ec3c47bb75592a91d62/metis).

Comment: Read about **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**, e.g. follow links about it [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/289020/40065)

Comment: Hope I will not have to dig in METIS code to find this kind of bug... (I guess the error is from me).

Comment: What about this: *`// Number of nodes in the mesh (15 points). #define NN 16`* so if you have told functions there is one more than there actually is, that could be UB. Or is the comment just a typo?

Comment: If I read the METIS API doumentation correctly, then certain parameters may be NULL, such as options. However, there is a difference between passing a pointer to an object that is NULL or passing the value NULL. You pass a NULL object whereas METIS might expect the parameter value NULL. e.g.: `METIS_PartMeshNodal(&ne, &nn, ..options,..)` should be `METIS_PartMeshNodal(&ne, &nn, ..NULL,..)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane good catch, thanks! However the error was in the comment, I just fixed in [here](https://github.com/dfroger/quickstart/commit/4d50b9fb9c2100ee67bce4cd75fa4d7ab86e7202)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks for pointing this! I fixed it [here](https://github.com/dfroger/quickstart/commit/a05c861119970fe72e02605652a5a92034dee5df), but I still get the same different values on GNU/Linux and OSX...

Comment: I'm going to debug with GDB and LLDB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`METIS` make use of pseudo-random numbers.

The pseudo-random numbers are generated by `GKlib` functions. (`GKlib` is embedded inside `METIS` tarbarlls).

By default, `GKlib` uses the `rand` function from the C standard library, which may generates different number on different platforms. (see: [Consistent pseudo-random numbers across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922358/consistent-pseudo-random-numbers-across-platforms)).

But `GKlib` can also be compiled with the flag `-DUSE_GKRAND`. Instead of using the `rand` function, it uses its own, which always give the same random numbers of different plateforms.

Compiling with `-DUSE_GKRAND` the `C` code in the function give the same results on my `GNU/Linux` and on my `OSX`:

```
objval: 18
epart: 0 0 0 2 1 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 
npart: 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 
8
```

I've used this conda [recipe](https://github.com/dfroger/df-conda-recipe/tree/b9c254aeba04688ac65703f8feb5d5003565dc2d/metis-gkrand) to build `METIS`.